# How to read a specific HTML part in a C++ program?

Tags: html, c++, command-line-interface, text-files

I am a very beginner. I have a C++ program in CLI, with a HTML/XML input file thanks to a `ifstream file("C:/.......")`.

The main problem is I want to take some text in this file, and put into variable. But the difficulties I meet is that I only want to take some part of the file, for instance in a `var1`. I want text which is between the HTML tag `<name>` or the one I choose.

I already tried to put some getline with condition or move cursors but I only have all the text or nothing.

```
//here some part of the code that i'm sure of

string info(""), line(""), system("");

ifstream file("C:/Users/[...]/file.xml"); 


if (file.is_open())
{
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    file.close();
}
else
    cout << "file is not open" << endl;
```

Then I call the var with the the text, sorry for English mistakes or code mistakes, and thanks in advance if you could give me some clues.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say hi, it's my first post i thought it was good

Comment: if you're looking to parse HTML in C++, take a look at https://github.com/lexborisov/myhtml

Comment: of it seems very coplete, i'll try to deal with this in a first time, thanks

Comment: Parsing XML (and HTML) is a _hard_ problem. If you want to do it properly use a library.

Comment: @Biffen do you have one to adivise me please ?

Comment: @FlyingWater [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) has always been my favourite.

Comment: I am not familiar with this kind of stuff, so i'll check that, hoping it will be helpful !

Comment: Search [softwarerecs.se] for "c++ xml library".

Comment: it seems mandatory to use a library, i don't master this yet, but thanks i will try with this too